# How do I concurrently build a List<Task> while executing it

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have a list of tasks which I want to populate.
While it is populating I want another thread to take the tasks that already exist and execute them.

Basically I want to create a backlog of tasks that is being cleared as it fills.

```cs
var taskList = new List<Task>;
for (i=0, i<10, I++)
{
    //Do Some stuff
    taskList.Add(SomeTask);
}

foreach (var task in TaskList)
{
    Execute(task);
}
```

Is there a way I can do this at the same time instead of having to wait for the task list to populate entirely first?

Comment: Sounds like you want a `BlockingCollection<T>`? See the example on its [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Are you talking about the [`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task) type? If yes, could you describe what the `Execute` method does with the supplied `Task` argument? Does it invoke the [`Task.RunSynchronously`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.runsynchronously) method or something?

Comment: `Task`s are not `Thread`s. You don't need to "start" or "execute" them. As soon as you invoke them, as with `taskList.Add(SomeTask);`, the task is live (running). Even if you want to queue the Task to run on a separate thread using `Task.Run()`, you still don't need to have a separate `Execute()` call. The threadpool takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to start the Tasks before you add them to the list.  To do this simply use `Task.Run()` instead of `new Task()`. Or if your Tasks are returned by an Async method, those task will already be started when the method returns the Task. See

> The following example is identical, except that it used the
> Run(Action) method to instantiate and run the task in a single
> operation. The method returns the Task object that represents the
> task.

```
   public static void Main()
   {
      var list = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
      string[] dirNames = { ".", ".." };
      List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
      foreach (var dirName in dirNames) {
         Task t = Task.Run( () => { foreach(var path in Directory.GetFiles(dirName)) 
                                       list.Add(path); }  );
         tasks.Add(t);
      }
      Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
      foreach (Task t in tasks)
         Console.WriteLine("Task {0} Status: {1}", t.Id, t.Status);
         
      Console.WriteLine("Number of files read: {0}", list.Count);
   }
```

[Task Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Question asks to have all the tasks execute in one thread (but not the thread setting them up).  `Task.Run` will use a separate thread per task won't it?

Comment: I didn't read it like that.  But that can be acomplished by switching out the Task scheduler. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-5.0

Comment: The original question doesn't specify whether the work is IO-bound and can be run on the calling thread, or if it is CPU-bound and must be queued to run on threadpool threads using `Task.Run()`. At the very least, more context is needed to determine which approach is appropriate. Advising to use `Task.Run()` without context could place a lot of unnecessary pressure on the threadpool, which is especially problematic in ASP.Net applications.

Comment: I don't understand that comment.  I don't even know how to make a Task run "on the calling thread".

Comment: Asynchronous methods that return Tasks execute on the thread that invoked them by default. Using `Task.Run()` queues the work to be run on the threadpool, which consumes threads. For the example you shared, `Task.Run()` makes sense because `Directory.GetFiles()` is synchronous and will block the thread that invoked it. This is not necessary in all cases though, and can be actively detrimental in ASP.Net environments if threadpool threads are consumed for purely IO-bound asynchronous work. OP's question doesn't include the details needed to determine what kind of work they are doing.

Comment: They only _start_ on the calling thread.  Any tasks they start, and the continuations after an await will typically be on a background thread.  The continuations will be on the calling thread only if the synchronization context requires it, like in WinForms/WPF if the calling thread is the UI thread.  And for Task-returning methods, the Tasks they return are already started when the method returns.

Comment: But I updated the answer to clarify that Task-returning methods return running Tasks.

Comment: Why use a `ConcurrentBag<string>` to store the results instead of a `ConcurrentQueue<string>`? The `ConcurrentBag<T>` does not preserve the insertion order. Instead with a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` you get out the results in the same order that you put them in.

Comment: That's just how the sample in the docs was written, but I imagine that it's just because the code doesn't use the insertion order.  And because the insert is on a background task, the order of insertion is meaningless as items can be interleaved in any order depending on the how the background threads get scheduled on the CPUs.

Comment: Yeap, I've seen too examples [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) not using an appropriate collection type. It's sad that they use a collection (`ConcurrentBag<T>`) specialized for mixed producer-consumer scenarios, in applications where the producer and the consumer is clearly defined and not mixed.